# Getting error when try to get difference tow date?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am getting one error when try to get difference two dates.

I am getting expires date from backend. This is give me this Date- `2022-09-15T17:00:00.000+00:00`

Now I have to difference this date to now date.

I try it i this way-

```
 const expires = new Date("2022-09-15T17:00:00.000+00:00");
 const now = new Date();
 const expiryTimestamp = new Date((+expires - +now) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24))
 console.log(expiryTimestamp);
```

But It is not working. In console I find this -

`Thu Jan 01 1970 06:00:00 GMT+0600 (Bangladesh Standard Time)`

But Why it print `1970`.

I also try without-

```
const expires = new Date(flash?.expires);
const now = new Date();
const expiryTimestamp = new Date((+expires - +now)))
console.log(expiryTimestamp);
```

But not working.

Comment: What do you expect `epiryTimestamp` to be?

Comment: The issue is because you're putting the result, which a floating point value of the differece in days, in a `new Date()`. JS Dates start at the epoch, so you're effecting saying `1970-01-01 + diff`. Remove the last `Date()` object and your code works. See the duplicate for more details.

Comment: @evolutionxbox, expiryTimestamp should be date formate

Comment: So what do you think the value _should be_?

Comment: Can you see value print `1970` but why, here time is `2022`.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, Hello, can you describe more. I actually stacking.

Comment: There's nothing I could add which isn't already described in the duplicate